# Problems on github with cypress drag and drop

Tags: github, drag-and-drop, cypress

I have test where I test drag and drop element. In localhost is everything ok. When I do pull request on github the test falls on the drag and drop movement. Do you have any advice what I can do?I am using this code.

```js
cy.dragAndDrop('[style="width: 843px; height: 230px; position: absolute; transform: translate(10px, 10px); z-index: 0;"] > .rounded-xl > .absolute > .pt-4 > .drag-handle','[style="transform: translate(10px, 490px); width: 843px; height: 230px; position: absolute;"] > .rounded-xl > .flex-col' )
cy.dragAndDrop('[style="transform: translate(10px, 10px); width: 843px; height: 230px; position: absolute; z-index: 0;"] > .rounded-xl > .absolute > .pt-4 > .drag-handle','[style="transform: translate(10px, 250px); width: 843px; height: 230px; position: absolute;"] > .rounded-xl')
```

here is the commands.ts part:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('dragAndDrop', (subject, target) => {
  Cypress.log({
    name: 'DRAGNDROP',
    message: `Dragging element ${subject} to ${target}`,
    consoleProps: () => {
        return {
            subject: subject,
            target: target
        };
    }
  });
  const BUTTON_INDEX = 0;
  const SLOPPY_CLICK_THRESHOLD = 10;
  cy.get(target)
    .first()
    .then($target => {
        let coordsDrop = $target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        cy.get(subject)
            .first()
            .then(subject => {
                const coordsDrag = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                cy.wrap(subject)
                    .trigger('mousedown', {
                        button: BUTTON_INDEX,
                        clientX: coordsDrag.x,
                        clientY: coordsDrag.y,
                        force: true
                    })
                    .trigger('mousemove', {
                        button: BUTTON_INDEX,
                        clientX: coordsDrag.x + SLOPPY_CLICK_THRESHOLD,
                        clientY: coordsDrag.y,
                        force: true
                    });
                cy.get('body')
                    .trigger('mousemove', {
                        button: BUTTON_INDEX,
                        clientX: coordsDrop.x,
                        clientY: coordsDrop.y,
                        force: true
                    })
                    .trigger('mouseup',{force:true});
```

Comment: Please add your code in the question. Refrain from using images of your code snippet.

Comment: sorry, i am new to all this
post updated with code